# Rigify Super Finger: Wrong action center for scaling

Tags: rigify

I'm new to Bleder 2.8 (coming from Modo) and I'm having some trouble with scaling (bending) a super finger with Rigify.

Here is what I did:
I added a Human Meta Rig to my scene and I did a few allignements to the bones in order to match my model. Then I generated the rig and parented it to my model using automatic weight.

Here is the problem:
I try to bend a finger by grabbing the handler and scaling it. I would expect, that the bending happens with the root of the super finger bone as action center. Instead, the scaling happens with the cursor as action center (see image).

[image]

Thank you for your help.

PS: I'm aware that allignment and axis of the finger bones are far from perfect, but I guess that's not the source of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a Rigify problem. In the screenshot, I can see that you have set the **Pivot Point** to **3D Cursor**. See image.

**Bounding Box, Individual Origins** or **Active Element** will give you the result you're after. Definitely invest some time and learn about the Pivot Point modes.

[image]

Comment: Oh, how embarrassing. This did it, thanks for your help!